# Get all activated fonts in Windows 10 using PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, fonts

I am trying to get a list of all activated fonts. This should include fonts activated by [FontBase](https://fontba.se/) and Adobe Creative Cloud.

I've verified that the fonts activated by the 2 font managers are available at the font dropdown in Adobe Photoshop.

I've tried the following commands in Windows PowerShell (Admin mode):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
[Windows.Media.Fonts]::SystemTypefaces
```

I also tried using `System.Drawing`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Drawing.FontFamily]::Families
```

Both commands give the same results and doesn't include the fonts activated by FontBase and Creative Cloud.

How do I effectively get a complete list of fonts like how Adobe Photoshop did?

Comment: Does this help https://superuser.com/questions/760627/how-to-list-installed-font-families/760632

Comment: Hey... that works. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helps  you